# Classification Accuracy Only 5% Higher Than Random Picking

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, ipython, classification, feature-selection

I am trying to predict a public DotA 2 match outcome with given hero picks. It is usually possible for a human. There could only be 2 outcomes for a given side: it is either a win or a loss.

In fact, I am new to machine learning. I wanted to do this mini-project as an exercise but it already took 2 days of my time.

So, I made a dataset of around 2000 matches with about the same skill bracket.  Each match contains exactly 13 000 features. Each feature is either 0 or 1 and specifies whether radiant have certain hero or not, whether dire have certain hero or not, whether radiant have one and dire another at a time (and vice versa). All combinations sum up to around 13000 features. Most of them are 0, of course. Labels are also 0 or 1 and indicate whether Radiant team won.

I used different sets for training and for testing.
Logistic regression classifier gave me 100% accuracy on training set and around 58% accuracy for test set.

SVM on the other hand scored 55% on training and 53% on test. 
When I decreased number of examples by 1000 I've got 54.5% on training and 55% on test.

Should I continue increasing number of examples? 
Should I select different features?

If I add more combinations of heroes feature number will explode. Or maybe there is no way to predict match outcome judging only on the heroes selected and I need to gain data about each players online rating and hero they selected and so on?

Plot of prediction accurace based on number of training examples:

[image]

Check out 2 latest graphs I added. I  think I've got pretty decent results.
Also:  
1. I asked 2 friends of mine to predict 10 matches and they both predicted 6 right. This amounts to 60% just as you said. 10 matches is not a big set, but they wont bother with bigger ones.
2. I downloaded 400 000 latest dota matches. MMR >3000, only all pick mode. Assuming that 1 billion dota matches are played each year 400k are from the same patch.
3. Concatenating hero picks of both sides was the orginal idea. Also, there are 114 heroes in dota, so I have 228 features now
4. In most matches odds are more or less equal, but there is fraction of picks, where one of the teams has advantage.From small up to critical.

What I ask you to do is to verify my conclusions, because results I've got are too bright for linear model.

[Probabilities test][2]

[Actual probabilites and predicted probability ranges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCabo.png)

[distribution of predictions by probability range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jZTG.png)

Comment: These classifiers will do no good considering the number of features and eventually will have poor generalisation power (test metrics have proved it). I even doubt that in your case the dimensionality reduction techniques will be adequate judging from the empirical side. I think ensemble methods will perform much better: take a peak at [RF](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) and [XGB](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost).

Comment: Even better option in my opinion would be [wide and deep learning](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide_and_deep) as it would combine strategy correlations between hero picks and basic generalisation power on out-of-sample data. However, it would take a tremendous amount of time just to set the data ready to be fit in `DNNLinearCombinedClassifier()`

Comment: You concluded that generalization power will be poor because accuracy isn't always growing with number of examples, right?

Comment: The bigger the training data, the more consistent the classifier will be during the prediction stage. Also, in general, bigger access to the input data leads to higher values of the used metrics. I have stated that the structure of the input data you use is barely applicable with the logistic regression.

Comment: Your Log. Regression model overfitted the training data due to too many feature. Did you try to add L1 regularization? This will, effectively, reduce your features and possible increase the test accuracy.

Comment: @Stergios I reduced number of features to 229. So only heroes selected, no combinations. With 400 000 matches still got accuracy of 59%. BUT I also tried linear regression to at least predict probability of team winning. I added picture of my self made test. Results look incredible, but model gets model.score() of 0.04. Does it mean my model works fine?

Comment: When you say 'linear regression' do you mean 'logistic regression'? Because with simple linear regression you cannot predict probability of winning.

Comment: @Stergios Hm,I meant linear regression. I trained it to give me value from 0 to 1. Look at the plot I made. Y axis is probability observed on certain subset of matches and X axis is predicted probability range for this subset.

Comment: As far as what you can expect from a linear model, it seems like you're about on target. It should be pretty close to the highest winrates heroes in the skill bracket. Typically ~60% is the highest you'd see, and ~40% is the lowest you'd see so, pretty much confirms the results you're seeing. It's probably just figuring out hero winrates and predicting on that (not bad, but there's likely headroom)

Comment: Hello, first if you can upload your data we could provide a better answer but until then you should use Random forests or ExtraTreesClassifier [linl](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier.html). Use also cross validation. An easy way is to use cross_val_score function [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html). Finally, you could use deep neural networks as classifiers. Again, if it is possible, upload your data

Comment: @ValeriiLos I can't see your images above. Links are not working. Why did you use simple linear regression to predict the probabilities instead of logistic regression?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is with your assertion that predicting a dota 2 match based on hero picks is "usually possible for a human". For this particular task it's likely more that there's a low cap on possible accuracy than anything. I watch a lot of dota, and even when you focus on the pro scene the accuracy of casters based on hero picks is quite low. My very preliminary analysis puts their accuracy at within spitting distance of 60%.

Secondly, how many dota matches are actually determined by hero picks? It's not many. In the vast majority of cases, especially in pub matches where skill levels are highly variable, team play matters much more than hero picks.

That's the first issue with your problem, but there are definitely other large issues with the way you've structured the problem that could help you get another couple of accuracy points (though again I doubt you can get far above 60%)

My first suggestion would be to change the way you're generating features. Feeding 13k features into an LR model with 2k examples is a recipe for disaster. Especially in the case of dota, where individual heroes don't matter very much and synergies and counters are drastically more important. I would start by reducing your feature count to ~200 by just concatenating hero picks by both sides. 111 for Radiant, 111 for Dire, 1 if hero is picked, 0 otherwise. This will help with overfitting, but then you run into the issue with LR is not a particularly good fit for the problem because individual heroes don't matter as much.

My second suggestion would be to constrain your match search for a single patch, ideally a later one where there's sufficient data. If you can get different data for different patches so much the better. An LR approach will give you decent accuracy for patches where specific heroes are overpowered, and especially at small data sizes you're a bit hosed if you dealing between patches as the heroes are actually changing.

My third suggestion would be to change models to one that's better at model inter-dependencies between your features. Random forest models are a pretty easy and straightforward approach that should give you better performance than straight LR for a problem like this, and has a built-in in `sklearn`.

If you want to go a bit further, then using an MLP-style network model could be relatively effective. I don't see an obvious framing of the problem to take advantage of modern network models though (CNNs and RNNs), so unless you change the problem definition a bit I think that this is going to be more hassle than it's worth.

Always, when in doubt get more data, and don't forget that people are very, very bad at this problem as well.

Comment: I edited initial post as response. 
I might try random forests and report results here.